# Unable to add hamburger menu to Reactjs code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive, nav

When my reactjs page hits mobile size screen hamburger icon shows but I am not getting how to add/open  panel when the user clicks on te hamburger icon.

```
<div className={styles["navbar-responsive-menu"]}>
     <Button theme="transparent">
           <HamburgerMenu size="32" color="var(--white-100)"/>
     </Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some type of logic to determine when to open and close upon click. [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) would be my go-to way.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// ...

const Navbar = () => {
    // 'nav' will store the value, 'setNav' will change the value
    const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
    // change the value of 'nav'
    const handleNav = () => {
        setNav(!nav)
    };

    return (
    // ...
    <HambergerMenu size="32" color="var(--white-100)" onClick={handleNav} />
    );
    // ...

};
```

Now you'll need to utilize some ternary operators (`:`, `?`) to change the className of the designated component that will render your actual menu.

```js
return (
    // ...
    <HambergerMenu size="32" color="var(--white-100)" onClick={handleNav} />
    // if nav === true, menuHide class, otherwise menuShow
    <div className={nav ? 'menuHide' : 'menuShow'}>
        <MobileMenu />
    </div>
    // ...

);
```

But you're likely also going to want an 'X' type of button to appear in place of the hamburger menu button when the actual menu is open, and, you'll likely also want the hamburger menu button to be hidden when the menu is displayed.

You're going to want to add a dynamic className to `<HamburgerMenu />` to hide when `nav === true`. Then, a `<CloseMenu />` that is hidden by default but appears when `nav === true`. This can all be done utilizing the same logic.

Hope the snippets above help.

Comment: can you show implementation of menuHide and menuShow.And i am using class based components :(

Comment: You'll just need appropriate CSS classes, like `.menuHide { dislay: none; }`. If you'd like I could edit this post to elaborate more?

Comment: Yeah @clxrity please elaborate it .Am new  to reactjs and i couldn't able to solve it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a state variable, for instance:
const [panelOpen, setPanelOpen] = useState(false);

Then when you click the hamburger, add an onclick event which would toggle the state, e.g.

```
onClick={togglePanel}
```

Then in the togglePanel function, toggle the state like so:

```
setPanelOpen(!panelOpen)
```

You then use conditional rendering to render the panel when the panelOpen variable is true, e.g.

```
{panelOpen && (
  ... Panel code
)}
```